# Contribution import fails for all records with error "No matching Contact found"

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, import, issues

I successfully imported contributions from csv files, up to 4.6.3.  Now when I try to import using the same saved mapping, in Joomla with 4.6.6, every record fails with the error

```
No matching Contact found for (person@example.com )
```

Is anyone else having trouble under 4.6.6?  My field mappings look correct, and the contact email addresses do exist as contacts in the database.

Comment: I would suggest you replicate on Demo site with some anonymised data.

Comment: Just checking: there isn't a space at the end of person@example.com, is there? Only that there is in the above.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but only with select import records. Symptoms: failed contribution imports all say "No matching Contact found for (external_ID)", even though I've verified the contact record exists. Drupal 7, Civicrm 4.6.6

Comment: Yes, the generated error file shows a space after each email address.  The source csv email addresses do not have spaces.  (I haven't had a chance to recreate on the demo site.)

Answer (score 1):

The only change to the file CRM/Contribution/Import/Parser/Contribution.php between 4.6.0 and 4.6.6 is the addition at line 263 of:

```
$params['contact_type'] = 'Contribution';
```

Commenting this out seems to fix my problem.  My contribution imports are based on matching the individual contact by email address, so I'm guessing that this line broke things by forcing a lookup by contribution ID.

Should I file a bug report?

Comment: I believe this is the same as the bug I filed last week, https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17163.  I haven't tried the fix, since I commented out that line - but there's a patch available, and it's going into Civi 4.6.9.